# How to do mutually exclusive attributes in XML schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xml-attribute

I'm trying to make two XML attributes to be mutually exclusive. How can one create an XSD schema to capture this kind of scenario?

I would like to have one of these

```
<elem value="1" />
<elem ref="something else" />
```

but not

```
<elem value="1" ref="something else" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [RelaxNG](http://www.relaxng.org/)  was mentioned in Alnitak's answer, here is a solution
with RelaxNG (a language which is, in most cases, better than W3C
Schema). Do note the OR (|) in the definition of elem:

```
start = document
document = element document {elem+}
elem = element elem {ref | value}
ref = attribute ref {text}
value = attribute value {xsd:integer}
```

If I have this XML file:

```
<document>
    <elem value="1" />
    <elem ref="something else" />
</document>
```

It is accepted by [rnv](http://www.davidashen.net/rnv.html) and [xmlint](http://xmlsoft.org/):

```
 % rnv attributes-exclusive.rnc attributes-exclusive.xml             
 attributes-exclusive.xml

 % xmllint --noout --relaxng attributes-exclusive.rng attributes-exclusive.xml 
 attributes-exclusive.xml validates
```

If I add in the XML file:

```
<elem value="1" ref="something else" />
```

I get validation errors, as I want (do note that the error messages
are suboptimal):

```
% rnv attributes-exclusive.rnc attributes-exclusive.xml    
attributes-exclusive.xml
attributes-exclusive.xml:4:0: error: attribute ^ref not allowed
required:
       after

% xmllint --noout --relaxng attributes-exclusive.rng attributes-exclusive.xml
attributes-exclusive.xml:4: element elem: Relax-NG validity error : Invalid attribute value for element elem
attributes-exclusive.xml fails to validate
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't do with attributes, but you can with child elements...

```
<element name="elem">
    <complexType>
        <choice>
            <element name="value"/>
            <element name="ref"/>
        </choice>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

This way you can have...

```
<elem>
    <value>1</value>
</elem>
```

or...

```
<elem>
    <rel>something else</rel>
</elem>
```

Comment: It can be applied to attributes using XSD identity constraints, see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately AFAIK you can't do that with XML Schema, I've had the same problem myself.

I've seen it suggested that if you need both of:

```
<elem type="xxx"> 
<elem ref="yyy">
```

then `<elem>` itself should be split into two types, since they've clearly got different attributes...

Comment: Is there any other schema language/style (other than XSD) where it would be possible?

Comment: @Filip: The only other schema language I know of is relaxNG, but I know nothing about it.

Comment: There's always xsd:annotation "Hey, don't include x and y on z".

Comment: I just posted an answer with a RelaxNG solution.

Comment: One could use post-processing (e.g, JAXB post-unmarshal listener as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976378) to validate that there is mutual exclusion.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it *is* possible to define this in XSD 1.0 using identity constraints via xs:unique or xs:key. Which one you choose depends on how elements without either of the two attributes shall be treated: They're valid with xs:unique but invalid with xs:key. The code sample below contains both variants; make sure to remove one of them, otherwise the "stricter" xs:key takes precedence over xs:unique, i.e., one of the two attributes is required.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="container">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="elem" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="value" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute name="ref" use="optional"/>
          </xs:complexType>
          <!-- Note: Use either xs:unique or xs:key -->
          <xs:unique name="attrsExclusiveOptional">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation>Ensure that @value and @ref cannot occur simultaneously.
Both may be omitted.</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:selector xpath="."/>
            <xs:field xpath="@value | @ref"/>
          </xs:unique>
          <xs:key name="attrsExclusiveRequired">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation>Ensure that @value and @ref cannot occur simultaneously.
One of them is required.</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:selector xpath="."/>
            <xs:field xpath="@value | @ref"/>
          </xs:key>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This validates the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
  <!-- Shall pass: -->
  <elem value="1" />
  <elem ref="something else" />

  <!-- Passes for xs:unique, fails for xs:key: -->
  <elem />

  <!-- Shall fail: -->
  <elem value="1" ref="something else" />
</container>
```

Answer (score 2):

XSD has abstract types for this: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1364846 (see post by tsuji)

Basically, you give the element at hand an *abstract*, complex type and define it's common attributes in there, which are *exactly* the same for all different use cases (not needed for your example).

Then you create 2 (or more) additional complex types which extend the abstract type I've just mentioned. Within *these* new types you define the differing sets of attributes between each use case. That's it for the XSD part.

Finally, you need to add a XSI `type` attribute to the resulting element in the schema instance document. So to be valid, the element must now have either one set of attributes or the other.

Not straight-forward, but flexible, and as we all know: the more flexible, the more difficult something becomes.

Comment: As far as it does solve the problem given I think it is – sadly! – an ugly solution. Somehow I hate it when I have to add those XSI attributes on my document just to cover up what I consider shortcomings of XSD. But maybe it is just me!

Comment: I certainly wouldn't call it elegant, and I try to avoid it when I can. This is where owning an XML IDE pays off.

Answer (score 1):

For readers coming to this later, note that the problem can be solved in XSD 1.1 using either "conditional type assignment" or assertions.