# How can I have JAXB call a method after it has completed unmarshalling an XML file into an object?

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

I am using JAXB to unmarshall an XML file into a Java object -- standard stuff.  Once JAXB has completed this, I'd like a method to be called on the newly created object.

Is there a mechanism to do this?  I'd prefer the object, not an external entity, do this to keep construction in one place.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand, you want a method to be called after the unmarshalling process automatically?

Comment: Yes; exactly.  Something like JUnit's @BeforeClass where a method is called after the construction and mutators are called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be able to execute code after unmarshalling took place, you need
an **[Unmarshaller-Listener](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.Listener.html)**

*However, I'm not sure, if the listener is invoked after the
properties are set or before.*

**NOTE:** The listener is available since JAXB-**2.0** (JDK-**6**)

Answer (score 39):

You can simple add the following method to your object definition:

```
void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent) {
  ...
}
```

It will be called once the current object has been completely deserialized.
See also the documentation about [unmarshalling callbacks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback)

Answer (score 18):

In addition to the Unmarshaller.Listener you can add the following methods to your domain model classes themselves.

- `public void beforeUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent)`
- `public void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent)`

From:
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.Listener.html