# Using JAXB to unmarshal xml with map-like structure to object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to unmarshal poorly designed XML into an object. The XML was built using a generic `type` element which can have any number of `items` with any `name`. Depending on the value of `type` in `Something` below, the include properties will be different. It's basically just bypassing the XSD rulse (yes, it has a XSD, but it's utterly useless).

The XML I get:

```
<Something type="actualType">
   <Property name="prop1">value1</Property>
   <Property name="prop2">value2</Property>
   ...
</Something>
```

What it should have been:

```
<actualType>
   <prop1>Value1</prop1>
   <prop2>Value2</prop1>
</actualType>
```

How it should be represented in Java:

```
@XmlType(name="actualType")
public class ActualType
{
   @XmlElement
   public X prop1

   @XmlElement
   public Y prop2

}
```

The actual question(s):

Is there any basic support for something like this in Jaxb (without external dependencies)? If not, can I write custom annotations such that I will be able to reuse the same logic for other services using this schema?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you could support this use case:

**OPTION #1 - Any JAXB (JSR-222) Implementation**

If you only need to read the XML to objects, then you could leverage a `StreamReaderDelegate` and do the following.  Basically it makes the bad XML appear as if it were the good XML:

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource("src/forum16529016/input.xml"));

        xsr = new StreamReaderDelegate(xsr) {

            @Override
            public String getLocalName() {
                String localName = super.getLocalName();
                if(!"Property".equals(localName) && super.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT) {
                    return localName;
                }
                if(super.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT) {
                    return super.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                }
                return localName;
            }
        };

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ActualType.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        ActualType actualType = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, ActualType.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(actualType.prop1);
        System.out.println(actualType.prop2);
    }
}
```

**OPTION #2 - EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy's) @XmlPath Extension**

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

MOXy has an `@XmlPath` extension that enables you to map this use case.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlType(name="actualType")
public class ActualType
{
   @XmlPath("Property[@name='prop1']/text())
   public X prop1

   @XmlPath("Property[@name='prop1']/text())
   public Y prop2

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Unfortunately I'd want to avoid external libraries.

Comment: @LewisDiamond - Depending on your environment MOXy may not be an external dependency.  MOXy is the default JAXB impl in WebLogic 12.1.1 (and later), and MOXy is included in GlassFish 3.1.2 (and later).

Comment: @LewisDiamond - Do you only need to worry about unmarshalling?

Comment: If you mean unmarshaling to a bad format such as the input, no. I'd unmarshal only to proper xml. Note that GlassFish or WebLogic are not available.

Comment: @LewisDiamond - I have updated my answer with an example of how you could use a `StreamReaderDelegate` to make the bad XML look like the good XML.  Since a `StreamReaderDelegate` is an `XMLStreamReader` you can have JAXB unmarshal it.

Comment: Indeed, I could use a different implementation of the reader. Alternatively I can create Item and Property objects and pass them to a factory that will take care of the creation. Is there no way to create custom annotation to work with Jaxb? (maybe through events?)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but you could simply read the bad xml's as they are in object Bad and then define the class Good with constructor Good(Bad bad).  The Good class would have the properties defined as members and its constructor would fetch them from the Bad object.

An alternative would be to have just one class, but keeping the "bad" members  private and then calling some method after the unmarshalling to fill up the good members (which are untouched by jaxb).  See [callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976378).