# JAXB: polymorphism and ignoring class as type when marshalling

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am using JAXB in order to marshal Java classes. I can't figure out which xml annotation i have to use in following scenario:

**XSD:**

```
...
<xs:complexType name = "Message">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name = "memberOne"  type = "xs:hexBinary"/>
        <xs:element name = "memberTwo"  type = "xs:unsignedByte"/>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name = "typeOne"        type = "MessageTypeOne"/>
            <xs:element name = "typeTwo"        type = "MessageTypeTwo"/>
            <xs:element name = "typeThree"      type = "MessageTypeThree"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
..
```

`MessageTypeOne/Two/Three` are defined before but aren't important to this scenario.

**Java classes:**

**Message.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Message", propOrder = {
    "memberOne",
    "memberTwo",
})
public class Message{

    @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(HexBinaryAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "hexBinary")
    protected byte[] memberOne;
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "unsignedByte")
    protected short memberTwo;
    //Which annotations i have to use here?
    protected MessageBody messageBody;

    ...
}
```

**MessageBody.java**

```
//Which annotations i have to use here?
public class MessageBody {
    //Which annotations i have to use here?
    MessageType myChoice;

    ...
}
```

`MessageBody` is not mentioned in the XSD file. It has to be "ignored" when marshalling. Only its class member `myChoice` must be marshalled.

I already thought about implementing my own `XmlAdapter` but couldn't find a way to solve the problem.

**MessageType.java**

```
public abstract class MessageType { ... }
```

That's the base class.

**MessageTypeOne.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MessageTypeOne", propOrder = {
    "memberOne",
    "memberTwo",
})
public class MessageTypeOne extends MessageType {
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "unsignedByte")
    protected short memberOne;
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "unsignedByte")
    protected short memberTwo;

    ...
}
```

`MessageTypeTwo/Three` are similiar to this one.

**Example XML output i can currently achieve:**

```
<Message>
    <memberOne>01020304</memberOne>
    <memberTwo>5</memberOne>
    <MessageBody>
        <MessageTypeOne>
            ...
        </MessageTypeOne>
    </MessageBody>
</Message>
```

**Desired XML output:**

```
<Message>
    <memberOne>01020304</memberOne>
    <memberTwo>5</memberOne>
    <MessageTypeOne>
            ...
    </MessageTypeOne>
</Message>
```

So i just want to remove the `<MessageBody> .. </MessageBody>` tag.

Obviously i just want to clarify the issue. In reality the code is much more complex.

I am NOT allowed to change the XSD file and only allowed to make minor changes to the java classes. I can NOT change the the relation of the classes to each other.

**My Questions:**

- Which annotations i have to use to skip the `MessageBody` class when
  marshalling? How can i tell JAXB to only marshall its member
  `myChoice`?
- How does polymorphism work in JAXB? Which annotation i need to use to
  achieve it?
- Is this issue as a whole solvable with JAXB?

EDIT: Added XML example outputs

Comment: Could you provide a concrete XML example (desired output)? That would make answers much easier.

Comment: Added and XML example now. Hope it helps to clarify my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Thomas Fritschs Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44226759/648901), who came up with the basic idea, i was able to solve the issue. I will basically use his code to answer my own question.

The problem i generally had to face was that i wasn't allowed to get rid of the `MessageBody` class. So i had to create a member `messageBodyChoice` in class `Message` to be able to access it directly.

Marshalling works fine at this point, unmarshalling doesn't. The XSD file doesn't contain a definition for `MessageBody`, so JAXB could never unmarshal it automatically.

To do this manually i added following method:

```
void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent) { ... }
```

(Watch this post for more detail: [How can I have JAXB call a method after it has completed unmarshalling an XML file into an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976378/how-can-i-have-jaxb-call-a-method-after-it-has-completed-unmarshalling-an-xml-fihttp://))

You can simply add this method to any class that gets un-/marshalled without any other effort.
with this method i was able to initilize `messageBody` after unmarshalling.

**Solution in code:**

**Message.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(name = "Message", propOrder = {
    "memberOne",
    "memberTwo",
    "messageBodyChoice"
})
public class Message{

    @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(HexBinaryAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "hexBinary")
    protected byte[] memberOne;

    @XmlSchemaType(name = "unsignedByte")
    protected short memberTwo;

    protected MessageBody messageBody;

    //This member is only needed for marshalling!!!
    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "MessageTypeOne",   type = MessageTypeOne.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "MessageTypeTwo",   type = MessageTypeTwo.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "MessageTypeThree", type = MessageTypeThree.class)
    })
    protected MessageType messageBodyChoice;

    //...

    /* 
     * This setter ensures that messageBodyChoice always contains
     * the value of messageBody.getChoice()
     */
    public void setMessageBody(MessageBody messageBody){
        this.messageBody = messageBody;
        if(messageBody != null) 
            this.messageBodyChoice = messageBody.getChoice();
    }

    //...

    void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent) { 
        //at this point messageBody is null
        messageBody = new MessageBody();
        messageBody.setChoice(messageBodyChoice);
    }
}
```

Note that i changed the `@XmlAccessorType` to `XmlAccessType.NONE`.
More information about `@XmlAccessorType` [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html).

This might look unclean but it's the only possible way i could find to avoid the `<MessageBody>` tag in the XML output.

Comment: Great that you solved everything! You should mark your own answer as accepted, and may be upvote my answer.

Comment: @Thomas I can't mark my answer until tomorrow and already tried to upvote your answer, but i need one more reputation. This message pops up: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Ah ok, no problem

Answer (score 2):

> How does polymorphism work in JAXB? Which annotation i need to use to achieve it?

You can achieve this kind of JAXB polymorphism with the
[`@XmlElements`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElements.html) annotation:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MessageBody {
    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "MessageTypeOne",   type = MessageTypeOne.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "MessageTypeTwo",   type = MessageTypeTwo.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "MessageTypeThree", type = MessageTypeThree.class)
    })
    protected MessageType myChoice;

    ...
}
```

#### Edit:

> Which annotations i have to use to skip the `MessageBody` class when
>   marshalling? How can i tell JAXB to only marshall its member `myChoice`?

You can remove the `MessageBody` class.
Instead put the `myChoice` property directly into the `Message` class.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Message", propOrder = {
    "memberOne",
    "memberTwo",
    "myChoice"
})
public class Message{

    @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(HexBinaryAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "hexBinary")
    protected byte[] memberOne;

    @XmlSchemaType(name = "unsignedByte")
    protected short memberTwo;

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "MessageTypeOne",   type = MessageTypeOne.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "MessageTypeTwo",   type = MessageTypeTwo.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "MessageTypeThree", type = MessageTypeThree.class)
    })
    protected MessageType myChoice;

    //...
}
```

Comment: This definitly solved my problem i had with polymorphism! Thanks!

Comment: @Truntle added solution for skipping `MessageBody`

Comment: This is actually something i came up with. It really works. But i am not allowed to delete `MessageBody` class. When unmarshalling i need to be able to create `MessageBody` again. I found a solution that doesn't look very clean but i think there is no other way in JAXB. I will post it later on.