# JAXB referencing ChildB in ChildA inheritance

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, reference, jaxb

I'm trying to unmarshall the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container>
    <childs>
        <child uuid="1" childB="3" attrA="specialAttrA1" />
        <child uuid="2" childB="4" attrA="specialAttrA2" />
        <child uuid="3" attrB="specialAttrB1" />
        <child uuid="4" attrB="specialAttrB2" />
    </childs>
</container>
```

As far as I can see this scenario contains two major problems:

- modelling the object hierachy
- referencing a subclass from within another subclass

The object hierachy consists of ChildA and ChildB which are subclasses of Parent (See the sourcecode below).

In the end the unmarshalled objects look good besides the references 'childB' which are null.

I couldn't find any example for this scenario. Debugging the source below questions me why the FlatParent object passed to the unmarshal-method of the Adapter doesn't contain childB.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Container {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "childs")
    @XmlElement(name = "child")
    private List<Parent> childs = new ArrayList<>();
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = ParentAdapter.class, type = Parent.class)
public abstract class Parent {
    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute
    private String uuid;
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ChildA extends Parent{
    @XmlAttribute
    private String attrA;
    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlAttribute
    private ChildB childB;
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ChildB extends Parent{
    @XmlAttribute
    private String attrB;
}
```

The corresponding Adapter looks like:

```
public class ParentAdapter extends XmlAdapter<FlatParent, Parent> {
    public Parent unmarshal(FlatParent fp) {
        Parent p = null;
        if (fp != null){
            if (fp.getAttrA() != null){
                p = new ChildA();
                ((ChildA) p).setAttrA(fp.getAttrA());
                ((ChildA) p).setChildB(fp.getChildB());
            } else {
                p = new ChildB();
                ((ChildB) p).setAttrB(fp.getAttrB());
            }
            p.setUuid(fp.getUuid());
        }
        return null;
    }
...
```

}

And the containing FlatParent:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FlatParent {
    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute
    private String uuid;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String attrA;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String attrB;
    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlElement
    private ChildB childB;
}
```

Just to be completely here is the part of the Testing class also:

```
@Test
public void testImportXml() throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Container.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    Container cont = (Container) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(FILEPATH));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two option I think:

1, Use an [unmarshaller-listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976378/how-can-i-have-jaxb-call-a-method-after-it-has-completed-unmarshalling-an-xml-fi), the drawback is that you have to read the XML twice and update your references manually after every involved object were unmarshalled

2, Read your XML as is, with numbers and convert them after unmarshalling to another pojos using a java bean mapper, e.g. [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) (In mapstruct, the fields with the same name mapped automatically and you can do this reference mapping in a decorator subclass)